# expand a glob string and pass resulting arguments to GNU parallel

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

In a bash script, I have a string with a glob character which would expand to a number of script paths/names that I need to process in bash and in parallel.

How to pass the resulting script names to parallel for execution?

I've tried the following, where `$string="./script*.sh"`

`(echo $string) | parallel`

`($string) | parallel`

with no success.

I even tried to read it into an array then construct a string of echos but that didn't help

`read -a scripts <<< "$string"
(${script[*]) | parallel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string=./script*.sh

# expand * here
echo $string | tr " " "\n" | parallel
```

Answer (score 1):

OR Try this:

```
parallel ::: ./script*.sh
```

OR

```
ls | grep script | parallel
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(echo $string) | parallel eval
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work, it seems that the `(echo $string)` doesn't expand the glob